# Splitting the Output of two commands in Shell script

Tags: bash, shell, redirection

I am using command like `timeout 10 ping 8.8.8.8 | tail -2`.

Here I am getting output as `Terminated`. But I need the last two lines of `ping`.

Can any one please tell what to do

Answer (score 0):

I have to use `&>` operator.

`timeout 10 ping 8.8.8.8 &>out.txt` and `cat out.txt | tail -2` would give the last two lines of `ping`

Answer (score 0):

You have found an answer, but you could also try

`ping -w10 8.8.8.8`

This tells ping to keep pinging for 10 seconds, then to stop.

Comment: ping is just an example. I want that functionality